# Prove for each infinite set $X$ exists surjective and injective function $f: X \to X$ such that $f\circ f=I. (…\text{except }f(x)\neq x)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove for each infinite set $X$ exists surjective and injective function $f: X \to X$ such that $f\circ f=I.
(\text{except }f(x)\neq x)$

**My solution :**

I thought to define $R$ equivalence relation such that $ (a,b)\in X^2 \iff f(a)=b , f(b)=a.$

Each equivalence class size is $2$ ,and there are $|X|$ equivalence classes.

But I really don't know how to prove it, this solution is correct ?

I'd be grateful for your some help!

Comment: When you say "except $f(x) \neq x$", do you mean for *some $x$* (i.e. $f$ is not equal to the identity map $I$), or for all $x$ (i.e. $f$ is a derangement)? In both cases, $X$ need not be infinite for this to hold; so long as $X$ contains at least two elements, such a map will exist.

Comment: @Theo: Only that choice is needed in the case of infinite sets and derangements.